# Castle Windsor kernel.Resolve not resolving for the types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am working on a MVC application with DI Castle Windsor (Version 2.5.1.0).  In the `WindsorControllerFactory`, I have the following code,

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }
    return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
}
```

I get the following exception

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=No component for supporting the service NN.XX.YController was found
  Source=Castle.Windsor
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service)
       at Permal.BSG.Manager.WebUI.WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\Dev\Apps\WindsorControllerFactory.cs:line 61
  InnerException:
```

But when I replace `kernel.Resolve` with the following, it works

```
return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType.FullName, new Dictionary<string,string>());
```

Can anyone help me figure out the issue, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you register your controllers?

Comment: IoC.Container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().
                BasedOn(typeof(XX.Manager.WebUI.Controllers.ControllerBase)).WithService.
                FromInterface().Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.PerWebRequest)));
            var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(IoC.Container.Kernel);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

Answer (score 0):

**You have this issue because of wrong type registration.**

**`.WithService.Self()` should be used** instead of `.WithService.FromInterface()` since `ControllerFactory` tries to resolve controller using it's concrete `controllerType` (e.g. YController).

```
return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
```

I use the following registration usually:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IController>()
    .WithService.Self()
    .Configure(it => it.LifeStyle.Transient));
```